# How to iterate array correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, iterator

I have a `$content` variable, `echo $content` shows the following :

```
{
   "ID": 181271,
   "version_id": 2137,
   "theme_id": 2,
   "score": null,
   "showstopper": 0
}
```

Obviously `echo $content['ID']` should shows `181271`

So I need to iterate all fields. I'm doing:

```
 foreach ($content as $key => $value) 
 {
      echo $key ;
      echo $value;
 }
```

And it gives me some crazy result!

```
incrementing 1 exists 1 wasRecentlyCreated timestamps 1
```

**Expected result:**

```
ID 181271
version_id 2137
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hope this will work, PHP code demo](https://eval.in/760291)

Convert json string to array with this `$array = json_decode($content, true);`

```
$content = '{"ID":181271,"version_id":2137,"theme_id":2, "score":null,"showstopper":0}';
$array = json_decode($content, true);
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For it is a json string, not an array. You have to json_decode in into an array. Then you can access it.